# Cucumber and persistant sessions across redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

Im using

```
rails - 2.3.8
cucumber - 0.8.5
cucumber-rails - 0.3.2
capybara - 0.4.0
```

I am trying to test a particular login/registration scenario where the user is redirected before landing on the required page. On redirect, cucumber flushes the session ie the user is no longer logged in.

Any ideas on how to prevent this?

*EDIT*

The feature im trying to test is as follows:

```
Feature: Check Register and SignUp  
    In order to use products
    As a User
    I want to register and login

    @javascript
    Scenario: Register on Landing Page
            When I go to Landing Page
            And I fill in "user_email" with "test@test.com"
            And I fill in "user_email_confirmation" with "test@test.com"
            And I fill in "user_password" with "testpass"
            And I select "State" from "state"
            And I press "Register Free"
            And I wait until Ajax requests are complete
            Then I should be on Home
```

When i add `And show me the page` to the feature, i see the `Landing Page` again.

*Edit 2*

I'm using restful_authentication for authentication.
The actual working is, when the form submits, the user is taken to a page and then redirected to the home page. This works when testing manually, but not when using cucumber.

*Edit 3*
Code formatting

Comment: We need code, not a gemfile. Give us your features and we would have a whole lot better idea of how to help you.

Comment: Also it looks like this is a known issue https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/353

Comment: @devin: Ive updated the question to include the feature and also, im not using omniauth for authentication.

Comment: Are you redirecting to the path or the URL?

Comment: The code in the controller that does the redirection is: `def check_logged_in
    if !logged_in?
      redirect_to junior_generic_landing_path
    end
  end`

Comment: Is it relevant? should i add it to the question?

Comment: Redirect to the URL see if the problem goes away.

Comment: You mean i should redirect to `http://myurl.com/home`?

Comment: no use the url helper. `junior_generic_landing_url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps a silly detail, though have you double checked that the url of the paths you've set match the site host in your cuke config? This bit us for a while while testing some cross-site JSON-P stuff...

Comment: Managed to solve this the next day after asking the question, but yes, this was the problem.